# Codeigniter Edit Error -> Call to undefined method

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>   **Severity:** Error
>   **Message:** Call to undefined method Post::where()
>   **Filename:** models/post.php
>   **Line Number:** 23

This is my edit controller

```
function editpost($postID){
    $data['success']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $data_post=array(
            'title'=>$_POST['title'],
            'post'=>$_POST['post'],
            'active'=>1
        );
        $this->post->update_post($postID,$data_post);
        $data['success']=1;
    }
    $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($postID);
    $this->load->view('edit_post',$data);
}
```

this is my update model

```
function update_post($postID,$data){
        $this->where('postID',$postID);
        $this->db->update('posts',$data);
    }
```

I changed the `data_post` - data same error

Where is my error?

Comment: a small mistake found in your model function **update_post**.put **db** in the place of $this->db->where('postID',$postID);

Answer (score 2):

put `$this->db->where('postID',$postID);
        $this->db->update('posts',$data)` in your model code

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow code:

```
function update_post($postID,$data){
    $this->db->where('postID',$postID);
    $this->db->update('posts',$data);
}
```

Please change your `update_post` function code from `$this->where('postID',$postID);` 
to `$this->db->where('postID',$postID);`. You missing `->db` before `->where` condition in your model page.

Thanks